# Background image is not displaying using either the style attribute or a Tailwind utility class

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, background-image

I am using Tailwind CSS to build a landing page that I have divided into sections. I want to use a background image on the particular `<div>` so that it only shows up in that section. I also plan to put a button and text box on top of it.

My attempt is just not working. I tried using `url()` in both a Tailwind `bg` class and a normal React `style` prop, but neither version works.

**Using the React style prop:**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import image from '../../public/images/Rectangle 37.png'
    
    const ReadySection = () => {
      return (
        <div
          className="border-solid border-2 border-sky-500 h-[300px]"
          style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image})`}}
        >
            
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default ReadySection
```

**Using the Tailwind utility class:**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    
    const ReadySection = () => {
      return (
        <div className="bg-[url('frontend\public\images\Rectangle 37.png') border-solid border-2 border-sky-500 h-[300px]">
            
        </div>
      )
    }

    export default ReadySection
```

I'm using create-react-app and named the app "frontend", so the path of the image is:

```
frontend/public/images/Rectangle 37.png
```

The path of my ReadySection component is:

```
frontend/src/components/ReadySection.js
```

Comment: spaces in tailwind arbitrary values need to be _. so it should be 'bg-[url('frontend\public\images\Rectangle_37.png')'